# ArcGIS Pro - Data joined back to original misses matches using Join

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I had a feature class with postcodes of Spain. Out of this I compared it to a different layer, performed some geospatial analysis and I have the output feature class that also contains the postcode from the original layer.

The type of the field is the same but for some reason, when I join the result of the analysis back to the untouched layer, I only get 627 matches, even though the result has 981 rows and they all exist in the original.

This is the result of the analysis - 981 records:
[image]

and the original:
[image]

I'm adding the join:
[image]

but for some reason, the join doesn't find all the values:
[image]

I checked and there are no selections or filters on any of the layers and despite the "0" at the beginning of some of those 981 postcodes, the field type is definitely `Text`.

Am I missing a step or two to make this join?

Comment: Do you have duplicate post codes in your new layer such that there are only 627 unique codes?

Comment: I used to because I thought that was an issue. I dissolved the layer on postcode and used dissolved layer for the join

Comment: I also double checked the data by exporting both feature classes' attribute tables to CSVs and joined them together. Even though the main layer still has duplicates, it correctly matched 981 unique postcodes from the second file

Comment: Are the fields built exactly the same? In this case, no domains and character length are equal? You might also try indexing the layers before running the join...

Comment: The field comes from the same layer and I also indexed them